# Get information from website by python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I come from Hong Kong, a new learner of python, I am going to scrap the information from below website:

https://event.hktdc.com/en/?eventFormat=Exhibition&countryRegion=Hong-Kong&location=all&year=2023&p=1

my code as below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get(
    "https://event.hktdc.com/tc/?eventFormat=Exhibition&countryRegion=Hong-Kong&location=all&year=2023&p=1#list")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

How can I get the information from it ?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? There are endless tutorials and guides online that help with learning to scrape websites with `beautifulsoup` - what problem did you run into trying to do it yourself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i think the problem is the data come from a dynamic website, should use selenium ?

Comment: Try using `urllib3` or `selenium`. I would use `urllib3` because selenium is very slow.